# Removing keychain data on uninstall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keychain

Does anyone know of a non-programatic method of removing data stored in the keychain when the application is deleted from the device?

I've read on several threads on SO that the data will persist even if the application is uninstalled and my experience confirms this is true.

However this seems contrary to what is specified in Apple's [iOS Application Programing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW5): "The keychain data for an application is stored outside of the application sandbox. If an application is uninstalled, that data is automatically removed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wipe the iPhone by using Erase all Contents and Settings.